# Making scripts use 1.8.7 and Rails use 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controls, version

In order to use my system management scripts that I have made for my system, I need to run them under Ruby 1.8.7. However, a Rails book that I am reading requires me use 1.9.2. I have both installed and know how to manually switch between them using rvm, but I wish for my system management scripts to be run with 1.8.7 without having me switch manually. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make 1.8.7 your default Ruby and add a `.rvmrc` to your Rails project:

https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: @ Michael Kohl Thank you very much for your advice, that will come in handy for my future projects.

Comment: @Mark: Glad to help! If that was the answer you were looking for, you should accept it by clicking the little tick mark next to the count so others know the question has been answered.